# Pass the svn version number to the bar file

Tags: svn, blackberry, blackberry-10

How can I pass the `svnversion` command output to the buildnum file?

Ok, I know I can pipe the output to it, but how can I integrate this in the QNX Momentics build process? So when I click "Build" it does this automatically for me.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the passed svn version? Display somewhere during runtime?

Comment: Yes, using the `version()` method of  `bb::ApplicationInfo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute any program in your build process by adding a new 'Builder'. Do this by going to Project->Properties->Builders.

Click on 'New' to create a new Builder and add in the path to your program. I don't use SVN so I'm using `/bin/echo` with `123` as the argument (this will be my build number).

[image]

Now go to the Build Options tab and specify the path to the `buildnum` file. This will pipe the output from your program into `buildnum`.

[image]

Ensure your new builder is first in the list of builders.

[image]

Now when you build your project your program will be run first and `buildnum` should be populated with your desired build number. Happy days.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried with my configuration however I keep getting this (not very informative) error: `Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'ePrintServices'.
The file does not exist for the external tool named SVN_version.
The file does not exist for the external tool named SVN_version.`

Comment: Got it, the `.exe` extension was missing... Windows ftl.

Comment: If you have found this answer useful consider upvoting it :)

Comment: I tried...=/ `Vote Up requires 15 reputation`

I hope this answer help someone else who can upvote for me :D

Comment: @BrunoR.Cardoso, I just upvoted your question, so you can upvote answers now.